# Constructor is undefined in ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am trying to populate a ListView control in an Android app. I have looked at many code samples and all seem to suggest doing it this way. However, when I try to implement this I get the following error:

The constructor ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.ReadJsonTask, int, ArrayList) is undefined

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        try{
            ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lstItems);
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(result);

            ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
            Iterator<String> looper = jsonObj.keys();
            while(looper.hasNext()){
                String key = looper.next();
                items.add(jsonObj.get(key).toString());
            }               
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
            lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        }catch(Exception ex){
            Log.d("ReadAdscendJsonTask", ex.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
    }
```

What is wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: Guessing this piece of code is from inner class? You might want to try ``MainActivity.this`` for Context.

Comment: Thanks! That worked, can you post this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems so that this piece of code is from inner class. And in such case `this` refers to this inner class instead of `MainActivity`. Changing `Context` parameter to `MainActivity.this` for `ArrayAdapter` should fix the error.